# Repast Simphony Projection customisation

Tags: projection, repast-simphony

I read in a book that a projection in Repast Simphony can be any user implementation of the Projection interface. I would like to create a custom projection but it looks more complicated that I expected. 
Have any of you ever tried to create their own projection? If so, would it be possible for you to explain how to proceed please? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think creating the Projection implementation should be fairly straightforward. However, it will not be integrated with the visualization architecture. So, your agents will be able to participate in the Projection but it will not be visualized.

If you implement a Class with the Projection interface and the ContextListener interface that should be enough. You can use the DefaultProjection as a starting point. Most, if not all, of the standard Projection hierarchies use the DefaultProjection as a starting point and their subclasses implement ContextListener. See AbstractGrid and ContextGrid, for example. The source should be useful as guide to implementation.